# Python Django MongodB mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, python-2.7, django-admin

How to connect a mongodB to django 1.8 or above???

```
DATABASES = {

'default' : {

      'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',

      'NAME' : 'my_database'

   }

}
```

it doesn't work..

Comment: have you added correct HOST, USER, PORT settings

Comment: What error u r getting? Did u try after installing Django MongoDB Engine.?

Comment: yeah i install mongoengine and toolbox 
and i changed setting.py as
MONGODB_DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "name": 'myDb',
        "host": 'localhost:27017',
        "password": '',
        "username": 'root',
        "tz_aware": True, # if you using timezones in django (USE_TZ = True)
    },
}

i tried this but it shows mongo is not a django backend database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 1.8 and MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256173/django-1-8-and-mongodb)